How can the classic Index Calculus from Western and Miller be used in multplicative subgroups?
Simple question derived from this answer, which stated this was possible…
And a second question about this is it really that much faster than targeting the whole ring ? I’m meaning the Number Field sieve and the Function Field sieve can be made to target multiplicative subgroups, but this only makes the Linear Algebra phase faster which means the complexity is still mainly determined by the the size of the finite ring instead instead of the size of the order/multiplicative subgroup. I’d like to know if this is the same for the classic index calculus.

The classic Western and Miller algorithm lifts elements $g^x\mod p$ to the rational integers and (using the prime factorisation structure of the rational integers) tests if the lift can be factored into primes below some bound. If so, this determines a relationship between exponents of notional elements that lift to these primes. Although these elements may not actually exist within the subgroup, the relationships must behave consistently. This can be formalised for a factor base prime $q$ and a  group of order $\ell$ by considering the lift of $m=q^{(p-1)/\ell}$ (which lies in the subgroup) and taking the notional exponent associated with $q$ to be the appropriate multiple of the exponent corresponding to $m$. Thus the method transfers.
As with NFS, the size of the integers tested for smoothness is the same whether we are discussing the full multiplicative group or a subgroup thereof and the only saving is in the modulus used in linear algebra. This saving is negligible in terms of the overall complexity.
